# I Keep receiving an "The MetaData is not bound to an Engine or Connection." when trying to create my SQL tables with pylons

Tags: python, pylons

Here is my current code:

```
def init_model(engine):

    global t_user
    t_user = sa.Table("User", meta.metadata,
    sa.Column("id", sa.types.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("name", sa.types.String(100), nullable=False),
    sa.Column("first_name", sa.types.String(100), nullable=False),
    sa.Column("last_name", sa.types.String(100), nullable=False),                
    sa.Column("email", sa.types.String(100), nullable=False),                    
    sa.Column("password", sa.types.String, nullable=False),                      
    autoload=True,                                                               
    autoload_with=engine                                                         
    )                                                                            

    orm.mapper(User, t_user)                                                     

    meta.Session.configure(bind=engine)                                          
    meta.Session = orm.scoped_session(sm)
    meta.engine = engine
```

I then try to execute:

```
>>> meta.metadata.create_all(bind=meta.engine)
```

And receive the error:

```
raise exc.UnboundExecutionError(msg)
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: The MetaData is not bound to an Engine or     Connection.  Execution can not proceed without a database to execute against.  Either execute with an explicit connection or assign the MetaData's .bind to enable implicit execution.
```

In my development.ini I have:

```
# SQLAlchemy database URL
sqlalchemy.url = sqlite:///%(here)s/development.db
```

I'm new to Python's pylons and have no idea how to resolve this message.  This is probably an easy fix to the trained eye.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was resolved.  I didn't know that when using pylons from the CLI, I have to include the entire environment:

```
from paste.deploy import appconfig
from pylons import config

from project.config.environment import load_environment

conf = appconfig('config:development.ini', relative_to='.')
load_environment(conf.global_conf, conf.local_conf)

from project.model import *
```

After this the database queries executed without a problem.